# Need program to loop correctly

Tags: loops, python-3.x

Got it.

```
while 1:
    line = sub.readline().split()
    if line == []:
        new = main
        break
    else:
        new = main.replace(line[0],line[1])
        main = new
```

This seem to work for me.  Thanks for the help =).

Comment: Your if else block is indented improperly

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Cameron, this method will overwrite the output file every time thus recording only your last change.

The error in this block is :

```
while True:
   word = substitute.readline().split()
   print(word)
   if word == []: // ---Indentation ---
       break
   else:
       new = (main_story.read().replace(word[0],word[1]))
       new_story.write(new)
```

You need to read the complete file at once, make changes and write to file. 
Or you could read from the first file, and then do subsequent read/writes on the new file.

Comment: This won't work since the output file is continuously being overwritten, not updated (and the file can only be read once).

Comment: @Cameron Yes, i didnt really look for that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try another loop and in that loop index the word swap that you need to occur:

I assume each line of sub.txt has the subs that you want.  Read all the lines of sub.txt, storing each line in an indexable array.  Set up a loop around your main code, and in that loop index through the array referencing, sequentially the line of sub.txt that you want each time.